# Intent. Сохранение выбора приложения

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
            Intent getIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            getIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            pickIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(getIntent, "Что вы хотите использовать?");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, new Intent[] {pickIntent});

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, MainActivity.FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);
```

Результат кода внизу на картинке.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, чтобы пользователь мог нажать "запомнить мой выбор".

В общем, мне нужен выбор между галерей и файлами с запоминанием выбора.

Или хотя бы со всеми приложениями, что могут использовать Type image.

Comment: тогда просто стартуйте Intent

Comment: Вам надо просто открывать изображение, система сама предложит приложения, и запомнить выбор